# Javascript Regular Expression not matching right

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the format I want to check against "3x12". The first number before "x" can be 2 digits but the first digit cannot be 0. This number(s) must be followed by the letter "x" and then again the same number format as before the "x".

Here is my regular expression:

```
/^[1-9]{1,2}[x]{1}[1-9]{1,2}$/g
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why is it not matching when I try "3x12" ?

Comment: _“The first digit cannot be 0”_ — then it should be `[1-9][0-9]*` and not `[1-9]{1,2}`. Also `[x]{1}` is just `x`.

Comment: Javascript is not Java.

Comment: It is matching `3x12`. You can try this in your browser console. `/^[1-9]{1,2}[x]{1}[1-9]{1,2}$/g.test("3x12")` evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @nnnnnn mentioned - your regex should be adjusted

```
var r, i, l, tests = [ "3x12", "doggy", "5x1", "41x44", "66x", "x3", "0x2", "0x0", "656x0"];
r = /^[1-9]\d?x[1-9]\d?/;
l = tests.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        console.log(tests[i], r.test(tests[i]));
}
```

**Output**

```
3x12 true
doggy false
5x1 true
41x44 true
66x false
x3 false
0x2 false
0x0 false
656x0 false
```